# OracleSolaris 11.2 -- similar mechanism to Linux procfs

Tags: filesystems, kernel, solaris, procfs, opensolaris

In Linux it is common to use proc FS as a means to talk with a kernel module, receive statistics from the kernel or set up some flags. What can be used for these in Solaris?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`procfs` was initially designed to permit access to process related information. On Linux, this goal derailed and various non process related pseudo files and directories started to be present there. This is slowly being  corrected by relocating (some of) them in `/sys` which uses `sysfs` and not `procfs`.

There has not been such issue with Solaris where `procfs` is strictly restricted to process data. One main difference between Solaris and Linux `procfs` implementations is Linux is often providing plain text data where Solaris is exposing binary structures.

For non process related statistics, the common Solaris interface is an API, [`kstat(3kstat)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5166/kstat-1m.html) which is used by many commands and can also be queried from the shell with the [`kstat(1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5166/kstat-1m.html) command.

The way to set flags and "communicate" with the kernel depends on precisely what need to be done, there is no single interface. It also evolved depending on the Solaris releases.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'm porting a Linux driver to Solaris 11.2, basically I re-implement Linux specific functionality on Solaris. The driver uses procfs for things like stats dump, underlying H/W register dump, setting debug level etc. So what Solaris-specific methods can be used to have these done in the driver?

Comment: You can create you own `kstats` to expose your driver statistics. For configuration, `ioctl` might be a suitable interface but that really depends of what kind of device driver you are developing/porting. Also make sure you are releasing/distributing your driver, if that's the goal, with a license that allows linking with proprietary code.

Answer (score 1):

What you'd do in Solaris is use kstats(3kstat) to provide info about your driver as @jilliagre mentioned. If you want to kick your driver to do things, then you should provide that facility via ioctl(2).